# Десериализация объектов из Json

Tags: json, java

Уперся в проблему преобразования файла .json в объекты Java. Опыта работы с Json вообще не имею =/. Json выглядит следующим образом:

```
{
"Ihar Novik": {
"position": "junior",
"salary": 10
},
"Delendik Stanislav": {
"position": "senior",
"salary": 20
},
"Oleg Nikolaev": {
"position": "middle",
"salary": 15
}
}
```

Нагуглил, там, где десериализуют один объект через json-simple (но там с проблемами со stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10926353/how-to-re..). С помощью какой библиотеки это будет сделать проще? И буду рад любой ссылке на пример.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте библиотеку GSON, очень просто и удобно. Качать [тут](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.google.code.gson%7Cgson%7C2.3%7Cjar)
Вот ссылка на доки GSON: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide
Тут разобрано на удачном примере: http://habrahabr.ru/company/naumen/blog/228279/